# How to take a row and create a list by removing duplicates and separating with a ;

Tags: excel, vba

It has been a little while since I have used macros so please be patient with me. I truly appreciate your expertise.

I am trying to create a list of unique values from a range that is separated by a ";" but I unfortunately do not have a strong enough knowledge base for this execution.

Currently I use this system: 
Select range (lets us A2:A100 for this example).
Copy and paste into a new sheet because I do not want to ruin the original sheet.
Remove duplicates from the list.
Copy and paste as transpose to make the list in a row.
Then run this macro

```
Sub insert_column_every_other()
For colx = 2 To 30 Step 2
Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next
End Sub
```

Then select the range and replace special, replace blanks with a ;
Then use CONCAT to make a list of all the cells separated with a ;

This is obviously not effective and there has got to be a better way!

I would like the macro to just read the list of A2:A100 in the original sheet and then create a list of the unique cell values separated by a ";". I would also prefer this pops up in a MSGBOX if possible.

Comment: This can all be done with TEXTJOIN.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am not familiar but I am researching that now.

Comment: Do you want help, it requires a non-standard use.

Comment: @ScottCraner that would be much appreciated. I am unsure of how to remove the duplicates but I have figured out how TEXTJOIN works on a very basic level.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @ScottCraner You rock! That is perfect. I will accept it as the answer in just a few minutes when it lets me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN as an Array Formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A2:A100,A:A,0)=ROW(A2:A100),FALSE),A2:A100,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

[image]